# How to prevent copying of digtal (handwritten) signatures?

Tags: physical, physical-signature

Assuming that you are not given any other choice than to implement digital handwritten signatures. That is, a signature pad (or even a computer mouse) is used to generate a digital signature which is stored as an image. The signature is part of an (authenticated) approval workflow. All users that are authenticated and authorised to view the approval can see the signature.

Since signatures are stored as images, when displayed in the browser, a signature can easily be copied without anyone noticing. **What measures can one take to ensure signatures are not being copied by the other users?**

Comment: Are you concerned about other people taking a screenshot of your signature and pasting it elsewhere?

Comment: potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235323/is-it-a-security-risk-for-a-signature-to-be-publicly-available  in fact, nearly all of the questions using the tag `physical-signature` apply.

Comment: @schroeder I agree that this may be a duplicate. However, I was not able to find an answer that includes the 3rd party witness aspect yet.

Comment: But you didn't ask about that. You asked about forgeries. And for that, this is a direct answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207640/how-do-living-politicians-protect-their-readily-obtainable-signatures-from-misus and the top answer talks about witnesses.

Answer (score 2):

A very short answer to this: **you can't**. And you **shouldn't need to prevent** this from happening.

A signature is simply a mark. It could be as simple as an X. It actually *proves* nothing and merely *indicates* that the "signer" processed the document. It can be argued that the handwritten signature is a memory aid *for the signer* to remember that they had signed it.

This is why legal documents include a witness to the signature. A 3rd party that can attest that the signer was the one who signed.

And this is the step that a digital workflow needs to include.

The signature/mark is never the point, but rather the 3rd party witness is. The system authenticates the signer and timestamps when the signer signs. In this way, it shouldn't matter if someone can copy the signature or whatever pretty picture someone draws on the digital pad (I know an infosec pro who signs everything as "Donald Duck").

"Digital signatures" (the cryptographic ones) offer more in terms of verification without user authentication at the time of signing and more portability outside of a company's systems, but that requires more of an infrastructure to handle that and to verify signatures. From what you've described, you seem to simply need an authentication step from your office systems when someone draws a pretty picture.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Since the system authenticates the user already, is a 3rd party witness still required?

Comment: It depends on whether your system satisfies the requirements of a 3rd party witness.

Comment: If you can draw an X on the pad, and you can then use the system to *prove* that you drew the X at that time and on that document, then yes. If you can insert images into the documents without authentication, then you run into challenges

Comment: Very interesting. I guess this quickly leads to the discussion of what authentication methods are sufficient tot prove you drew the X.  Any ideas on this?

Comment: It will depend on your systems and the level of trust that is required.